# Best way with ActiveRecord: If exists then delete else create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this route to create a Favorite for a certain Tip:

```
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  Favorite.create(user: current_user, tip: @tip)
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

I want it to be more like a toggle. So: If a favorite from a user for a certain tip already exists then it should delete this favorite. If it's a new combination of user and tip, it should create a new favorite with these values.

What is the best and most beautiful way to this?

Comment: If exist what and delete what ?

Comment: If the favorite by a user for a certain tip exists. The combination of user and tip is unique.

Comment: Describe more? the question is not clear, also i got it like, you need to delete if the Tip exists and else you need to create that?

Comment: I updated my question. I hope my description is more clear now.

Comment: I don't think a "toggle" is RESTful, I'd use separate PUT and DELETE actions.

Comment: This is a good point (y)

Comment: Definitely separate create and delete actions, otherwise you run the risk of deleting when the user thought they were creating and vice versa.

Comment: @Stefan Could you create an answer? I would like to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, I think its the most concise solution:

```
def favorite
  # Since this is about a favorite object, the main subject here 
  # is that favorite object, so you just need to deal with it
  favorite = Favorite.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: current_user.id, tip_id: params[:id])
  favorite.persisted? ? favorite.destroy : favorite.save
  # I do not know if you should redirect to this tip if 
  # the associated favorite has been deleted 
  redirect_to favorite.tip
end
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO "complex" logic like that belongs into a model:

```
# in you Favorite model
def self.toggle(user, tip)
  fav = where(user: user, tip: tip).first
  fav.try(:destroy!) || create!(user: user, tip: tip)
end

# in your controller
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  Favorite.toggle(current_user, @tip)

  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about first_or_create ([Link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create))? With that, this is how you can approach the problem:

```
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  Favorite.where(user: current_user, tip: @tip).first_or_create
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

This one might be tricky, so if there are any values you would like to pass to your Favorite object - regardless of creating or updating - you can do something like that:

```
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  Favorite.where(user: current_user, tip: @tip).first_or_create do |favorite|
    # favorite is the one found or the one that will be created
    favorite.rating = 5 # just an example how you can use it
  end
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

The changes will be persisted, and you still have quite clean code (no need for any `if`'s).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this. it may useful for you

```
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  @fav=Favorite.where(user: current_user, tip: @tip)
  if @fav !=nil
     @fav.destroy
  else
      Favorite.create(user: current_user, tip: @tip)
  end

  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

Comment: Something like this was my initial idea. I thought about a very short way to do this. But as Stefan commented under my post, seperate routes are the better way to go.

Comment: `@fav !=nil` can be written as `@fav.present?`

Comment: @angu: Yes, but it makes sense to use Ruby idioms if you write Ruby code, and `foo != nil` is not Ruby-sh.

Comment: You can abbreviate the condition to `if @fav`

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from everyone else's answers and using find_by

```
def favourite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  favourite = @tip.favourites.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
  if favourite
    favourite.destroy
  else
    @tip.favorites << Favorite.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  redirect_to action: :show, id: @tip.id
end
```

If you've got your routes set up using resources, the redirect will be

```
redirect_to @tip
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a method in your *Favorite* model

```
def self.toggle_favorite(tip)
  return tip.favorite.destroy if tip.favorite
  tip.favorite.create(user: current_user)
end
```

Then use that method in your controller

```
def favorite
  @tip = Tip.find(params[:id])
  Favorite.toggle_favorite(@tip)
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @tip.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **check** whether user is `adding new or removing the existing` by passing `identifier` to the server which will check available entries.Such as here,i check if user is adding a tag or removing a tag by liking or disliking a tag,hence is pass `like/dislike identifier` along with the url and then use it ..

**for example:Suppose user is  adding/editing /removing his favorite video tags.**

```
         def add_video_in_profile
            ##get all available tags
            @video_cat = VideoCategory.find_by_video_type params[:type]
              if params[:rel]=="Like"
              ##create new if not exits if like else delete selected item  
             current_user.user_video_categories.find_or_create_by_video_category_id(:video_category_id=>@video_cat.id) unless !current_user.user_video_categories.find_or_create_by_video_category_id(:video_category_id=>@video_cat.id)            
              else
             ##delete selected item if dislike              
            video_cat=current_user.user_video_categories.where(:video_category_id=>@video_cat.id)
                  video_cat.delete_all
              end    
            end
```